# Pandas: SettingWithCopyWarning for pd.to_datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 36)

filenames = glob('market_share**.csv')


data_all = pd.concat((pd.read_csv(i) for i in filenames))


df = data_all.loc[data_all['Product id'] == 'GOOGLE']

df.loc[:,'Market Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Market Date'])

print(df)
```

Why do I get SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
I already used for .pd.to_datetime .loc right? how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Change your last three lines to this:

```
df = data_all.loc[data_all['Product id'] == 'GOOGLE'].copy()

df.loc['Market Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Market Date'])

print(df)
```

You just need to `.copy()` slices of your dataframes when you're going to modify them.

Comment: What is the reason behind this warning?

Comment: @Sadra Basically I think they're trying to warn you that the changes you make to `df` (the slice) won't affect the original (`data_all`). In this case, that's fine, and `.copy()` tells pandas that it's intentional.

Comment: if i do that i get a ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis